# How to copy content of Rich Text Content Control from Word document and remove the control itself using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to copy the content of Rich Text Content Control(s) from one to another Word document. Each of Rich Text Content Control(s) contains a text block and a few of Plain Text Content Controls. The code below seems to work...

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
    Dictionary<string, SdtBlock> sdtBlocks = getContentControlsFromDocument(sourceFile);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SdtBlock> sdtBlock in sdtBlocks)
    {
        SdtElement control = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r =>
        {
            var tag = r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>();
            return tag != null && tag.Val == sdtBlock.Key.ToLower();
        }).FirstOrDefault();

        SdtContentBlock cloneSdtContentBlock = (SdtContentBlock)sdtBlock.Value.Descendants<SdtContentBlock>().FirstOrDefault().Clone();
        control.Parent.InsertAfter(cloneSdtContentBlock, control);
        control.Remove();
    }
    mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

but when I try to find all the Content Controls within the `destinationFile` using the code below

```
string key = "tag_name";
List<SdtElement> controls = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r =>
{
    var tag = r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>();
    return tag != null && tag.Val == key.ToLower();
}).ToList();
```

I can't find the ones that were/are within the Rich Text Content Control copied from the `sourceFile`. In other words, I'd like to copy only the content of the Rich Text Content Control without the control itself.

Update:

To simplify the question. I have a Rich Text Content Control which may have plain text and a couple of Plain Text Content Controls. All I need is copying (only) the content within this Rich Text Content Control which wrappes the whole thing to an other Word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I managed to solve the problem myself. Here is the solution so it might be useful to someone else.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\tmp\test-1.docx", true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
        foreach (var conditialTemplate in conditionalTemplates)
        {
            List<SdtElement> controls = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r =>
            {
                var tag = r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>();
                return tag != null && tag.Val == conditialTemplate.ToLower();
            }).ToList();
    
            foreach (var control in controls)
            {
                if (control != null)
                {
                    SdtProperties props = control.Elements<SdtProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
                    Tag tag = props.Elements<Tag>().FirstOrDefault();
                    Console.WriteLine("Tag: " + tag.Val);
    
                    string theRightBlock = "A";
    
                    SdtBlock theRightSdtBlock = GetTheRightConditionalSdtBlock(theRightBlock, tag.Val);
                    if (theRightSdtBlock != null)
                    {    
                        OpenXmlElement parent = control.Parent;
                        SdtBlock clone = new SdtBlock();
                        clone = (SdtBlock)theRightSdtBlock.Clone();
                        var elements = clone.GetFirstChild<SdtContentBlock>().ChildElements.ToList();
                        elements.Reverse();
                        elements.ForEach(child =>
                        {
                            parent.InsertAfter(child.Clone() as OpenXmlElement, control);
                        });
                        control.Remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mainPart.Document.Save();
    }
```